# Sending PDF Byte Array to Print

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I'm trying to get my web app to send a PDF document to a networked printer but, all of the examples I've seen all require a physical file to already exist, which doesn't work for what I need.

I have a service that given an id, returns an object where one of the properties is a byte array of the PDF document.

How do I send this to a named network printer?

I have tried evoPDF's PDFPrint, but it is rasterizes the PDF document before sending the content to the printer, which is inflating a 14KB file to over 40MB which seems ridiculous.

The evoPDF support said nothing can be done to change that, so I need to find an alternative.

The web app would be sending hundreds of 3/4 page documents at a time, and waiting for the printer to spool upwards of 50MB for each one is not acceptable.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this library http://www.terminalworks.com/pdf-print-net.
It should support printing from byte array.

Comment: Keep in mind it does cost and the current price is @ $300